# Instead Trigger or Calculated Column? which is better?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers, calculated-columns

I was wondering if there was any performance difference between the two approaches below.
Basically, the issue is we allow spaces and dashes in an id but certain legacy applications are unable to use these so they are stripped out.
As far as I can see the neatest way to do this is either in a trigger or as a calulated column. 
The SQL is shown below (cleaned up and anonymized so apologies if an error crept in)
So far on our test servers, there doesn't appear to be any difference between the two methods, does anyone else have any input?

[Database SQL Server 2008]
[Lookup table 20000000 rows and growing]

Option 1 - Create trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER triMem_Lkup on Mem_Lkup
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Mem_lkup
       SELECT ex_id, contact_gid, id_type_code, date_time_created,
              (replace(replace([ex_id],' ',''),'-','')) as ex_id_calc
       FROM inserted
END
GO
```

Versus
Option 2 - use a calculated column

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Mem_lkup](
    [mem_lkup_sid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ex_id] [varchar](18) NOT NULL,
    [contact_gid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [id_type_code] [char] (1) NOT NULL,
    [date_time_created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ex_id_calc]  AS CAST( replace( replace([ex_id],' ','')  ,'-','')  AS varchar(18)) PERSISTED

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Mem_Lkup] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [mem_lkup_sid] ASC
)
```

Which one is best?

Comment: This won't work the same on an update -- on an update the calculated would make a change, but this INSERT trigger would not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Computed columns will be best.

The `INSTEAD OF` trigger will create the whole pseudo `inserted` table in `tempdb` first.

[image: Plan]

For the trigger version with your `CREATE TABLE` statement (non clustered PK on a heap)

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;

INSERT INTO [_test].[dbo].[Mem_lkup]
           ([ex_id]
           ,[contact_gid]
           ,[id_type_code]
           ,[date_time_created])
SELECT type AS  [ex_id]
      ,1 [contact_gid]
      ,'A' [id_type_code]
      ,getdate() [date_time_created]
  FROM master..spt_values
```

Gives me

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 5076
Table 'spt_values'. Scan count 1, logical reads 15

Table 'Mem_lkup'. Scan count 0, logical reads 7549
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 15
```

Whereas the calculated column version is similar but avoids the `worktable` reads.

```
Table 'Mem_lkup'. Scan count 0, logical reads 7555
Table 'spt_values'. Scan count 1, logical reads 15
```

Is there any reason you are persisting this value at all though? (as opposed to having a non persisted computed column)

Comment: I thought that I needed to persist the calculated column as it is being used as part of an index. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx#BKMK_persisted)
Is that not correct?

Comment: @EoinO - Nope. Not for this case, only for imprecise (float) values or CLR functions/types.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, Your answers have been really informative!
Re: persisted comment, if you are running through thousands of records, would this value be calculated everytime?

Comment: @EoinO - Sorry, not sure why I never answered your question above. The value would be re-calculated every time you `SELECT`-ed it. But the greater number of rows on a page from not persisting it might balance that out. Even if persisted there is no guarantee that it won't be re-evaluated. See [Why does the Execution Plan include a user-defined function call for a computed column that is persisted?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5999986/73226)