# Update / Insert trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm new to SQL Server and triggers. I want to create a trigger that fires when new rows are inserted or existing rows are updated. The trigger will update a set of calculated columns.

Can someone give me a basic trigger that checks if `fldType = 'INVALID'`, if it is, it sets another column `errInvalid` to `1`.

Bare in mind that there will be 5000 rows inserted (in a single hit) per day so performance is an issue. I have looked elsewhere, but just getting confused.

OK, my question has evolved.  I've driven down the Persisted Colums route.  I've created a succesfull basic persisted field, but having trouble with a nested logic pf.

Can I (and how) do the following:

case 
   when [MissCustName] IS true then 
      when [CustomerAccountName] IS NULL then 
         (1) 
      else 
         (0) 
   end
else 
   (0) 
end

Comment: I think that you are confused with what a "calculated column" is. If it where a computed column, then you wouldn't need to update it, it would be automatic without the need of a trigger. It actually seems that this might be the best option for you

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  If so, post it here.

Comment: I can imagine someone opening archives of SO in 20 years and then going "In 2012 inserting 5000 rows per day into a database was a serious issue" ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe better option would be to use computed columns instead..

```
create table myTab
(
    fieldType varchar(10),
    errInvalid As Case When fieldType = 'INVALID' then 1 else 0 end PERSISTED
)
Go
insert into mytab(fieldType) values ('aaa')
insert into mytab(fieldType) values ('INVALID')
Go
Select * from mytab
```

Comment: I did consider calculated fields, but some I would need to carry out some kind of lookup and I don't want to have a performance hit, so thought it better to have static fields that are only changed when I UPDATE or INSERT?

Comment: "PERSISTED" keyword is just what you need.. If its "Persisted"- its calculated on insert/update.

Comment: OK, my question has evolved. I've driven down the Persisted Columns route. I've created a successful basic persisted field, but having trouble with a nested logic pf.

Can I (and how) do the following:

case when [MissCustName] IS true then when [CustomerAccountName] IS NULL then (1) else (0) end else (0) end

Comment: Case When fieldType = 'INVALID' then 1 else 
Case When otherField = 'value' then 2 else 0 end 
end /// just like any case statement..

Comment: GRRRR, think it's having issues referencing another persisted field.  Does it calculate persisted fields in order?

Comment: Not sure about that. But what you can do in any case- reference not persisted field, but put the code you have in that persisted field.

Comment: There's a lot of logic to put in one field, hence why I've split it down and then had a master (if A, B or C fail then totalFAIL = TRUE) kinda thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something along the lines of this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trgInsertUpdate
ON dbo.YourTableNameHere
FOR INSERT, UPDATE 
AS BEGIN
   -- update the column
   UPDATE dbo.YourTableNameHere
   SET errInvalid = 1
   FROM Inserted i 
   WHERE 
      dbo.YourTableNameHere.ID = i.ID   -- establish link to "Inserted" pseudo-table
      AND fldType = 'INVALID'
END
```

Basically, the trigger gets called **once** for each statement, so it might apply to multiple rows at once. Those rows and their new values are stored in the `Inserted` pseudo-table, which contains all the columns from your table.

You need to find those rows in your table where `fldType = 'INVALID'`, and which are also part of the `Inserted` pseudo table (those were inserted or updated).

Comment: @Bridge: yes - sorry - typing too fast :-) Thanks! Updated.

Comment: +1 I'll pretend I didn't notice the other 3 edits too. Slow down ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you want:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger1
ON Table1
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE t
    SET    errInvalid = 1
    FROM   Table1 t
           INNER JOIN Inserted i
             ON i.id = t.id
    WHERE  t.fldType = 'INVALID'
```

Answer (score 1):

You really want a calculated column.  It will peform better. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911882/instead-trigger-or-calculated-column-which-is-better) SO post.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myTab]
(
  [fldType] [varchar](50) NULL ,
  [errInvalid] AS ( CASE [fldType]
                      WHEN 'Invalid' THEN ( 1 )
                      ELSE ( 0 )
                    END )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a "real" computed column?

e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE foobar
(
    fldType varchar(10),
    errInvalid AS CASE WHEN fldType = 'INVALID' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
)
```

Using a persisted computed column would probably increase performance if you do a lot of reads (pretty much to the level of "physical" columns). Just add `PERSISTED` after the column definition:

```
CREATE TABLE foobar
(
    fldType varchar(10),
    errInvalid AS CASE WHEN fldType = 'INVALID' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PERSISTED
)
```