# Persisted computed field being recalculated during select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the Execution Plan include a user-defined function call for a computed column that is persisted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998217/why-does-the-execution-plan-include-a-user-defined-function-call-for-a-computed)

I've added a persisted computed column to a table.

```
ALTER TABLE guest
  ADD FullName AS
  dbo.complicatedFunction(ISNULL(FirstName, N'') + ISNULL(LastName, '')) PERSISTED
GO
```

I also added a non-clustered index on that field.

When I do a select from that table and include the column into a where statement it takes very long to execute.

I tried replacing the persisted column with the expression directly and it takes the same amount of time to execute, which led me to believe that FullName field is being recalculated for every row when I try to select something from that table.

How can I avoid that recalculation and get the query to use the index?

[image: Execution plan]

Comment: How are you using the column in your WHERE statement? Is there a LIKE?

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight It's the same if I use LIKE, CHARINDEX(Split.s, FullName)> 0, or even FullName IS NOT NULL. Any of those will take the same amount of time to run.

Comment: Try make a view with the column instead of a function

Comment: [Related/Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5998217/73226)

Comment: Please post the execution plans.

Comment: I learn something new here every day :)

Comment: @MartinSmith I've posted plans. But it is a duplicate question and it's answered very well on the link you posted.

Comment: The plans you have posted look to me as though @CodeByMoonlight's suspicion may well have been correct though! Can you right click the clustered index scan in the execution plan. View the properties and look at the output columns and see if `FullName` is being output? if so it is using the persisted value and the issue then becomes one of it not using your NCI because it isn't covering and selectivity issues in the `=` case (or maybe because an implicit datatype conversion makes the query unsargable)

Comment: @MartinSmith FullName is not in the Output List in those queries. It is added at the Compute Scalar step.

Comment: @MartinSmith The question you linked to solved my problem (I removed function call and moved the code of the function into the definition of the computed column and it works great now). Thank you very much.

Comment: i think you find here the answer


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998217/why-does-the-execution-plan-include-a-user-defined-function-call-for-a-computed][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998217/why-does-the-execution-plan-include-a-user-defined-function-call-for-a-computed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Martin Smith posted a link to a great explanation on why this is happening, and after reading through it, I replaced a call to the UDF with it's body and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The reason is that the query optimizer does not do a very good job at
>   costing user-defined functions. It decides, in some cases, that it
>   would be cheaper to completely re-evaluate the function for each row,
>   rather than incur the disk reads that might be necessary otherwise.

[Why does the Execution Plan include a user-defined function call for a computed column that is persisted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998217/why-does-the-execution-plan-include-a-user-defined-function-call-for-a-computed)