# SQL Server : use function to calculate a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've created a function that calculates the amount of business days between two dates using a calendar table to exclude holidays and weekends.

```
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.BusinessDays 
     (@sDate SMALLDATETIME, 
      @eDate SMALLDATETIME) 
 RETURNS TABLE 
 AS 
     RETURN (SELECT COUNT(*) dt 
             FROM dbo.Calendar 
             WHERE dt BETWEEN @sDate AND @eDate) 
Go
```

My question is: how do I use this function to compute a column from another table (`dbo.HolidayRequestForm`) which has two date columns?

I have tried

```
ALTER TABLE Test
    ADD HoursTaken AS dbo.BusinessDays ([StartDate], [FinishDate])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best thing to do would be to refactor your function to return a scalar value:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.BusinessDays
(
    @sDate SMALLDATETIME,
    @eDate SMALLDATETIME
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RTN INT;

    SELECT @RTN = COUNT(*) 
    FROM dbo.Calendar
    WHERE dt BETWEEN @sDate AND @eDate;

    RETURN @RTN;
END
```

Then your SQL to add the computed column remains the same.

If your function needs to remain as a table-valued function, you'll need to use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.HolidayRequestForm
    CROSS APPLY dbo.BusinessDays(StartDate, FinishDate) d
```

Which, as you can see, would make using a computed column quite tricky.

A couple of unrelated points:

- I'm not sure if `HoursTaken` is the best name of your computed column, since it seems to be storing the number of **days** (not hours) between the 2 dates.
- When using a date range in your query, it's advisable to use `WHERE DateColumn >= @DateStart AND DateColumn < @EndDate`. For more information, see [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries).

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I wasn't aware that SQL Server supported inline scalar functions (at least ones that pulled data from a table). Where could I find syntax/examples for that?

Comment: @zack - SQL Server does not support inline Scalar functions (except for in SQL 2019 -YAY!). T-SQL Inline Table Valued functions perform better for a whole host of reasons. Since you can't use Inline Table Valued functions for computed columns the OP could just use inline SQL; it will accomplish the objective without a crazy performance hit.

Comment: @Zack . . . That was some form of wishful thinking.

Comment: @conor8630 - I think so. Haven't had a chance to play with 2019 yet

Answer (score 1):

You are right to want to use inline (pure) T-SQL functions. There's two kinds of T-sql functions in SQL Server: Inline Table Valued functions and Wrong. Unfortunately, you can't use Inline Table Valued functions for computed columns and, if performance is remotely important, you **DO NOT** want to use a T-SQL scalar UDF for a computed column.

The good news is, you don't need to. You have a couple options. First, you don't need a calendar table to calculate working days, you could use this logic for your computed column:

```
CASE WHEN SIGN(DATEDIFF(dd, @startDate, @endDate)) > -1 THEN
                (DATEDIFF(dd, @startDate, @endDate) + 1) --total days including weekends
               -(DATEDIFF(wk, @startDate, @endDate) * 2) --Subtact 2 days for each full weekend
    -- Subtract 1 when startDate is Sunday and Substract 1 when endDate is Sunday: 
    -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @startDate) = 'Sunday'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @endDate)   = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

You could also use this logic to create an indexed view which is more flexible and *could* be a better option.

Here's a couple good links about why you NEVER use T-SQL scalar UDFs as computed columns, or constraints:

[A Computed Column with a (scalar udf) might Impact Query Performance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2011/11/28/a-computed-column-defined-with-a-user-defined-function-might-impact-query-performance/) –Kun Cheng (SQLCAT)

[Another Hidden Parallelism Killer: Scalar UDFs In Check Constraints](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/04/another-hidden-parallelism-killer-scalar-udfs-check-constraints/) – Erik Darling (this article applies to computed columns too)

[Another reason why scalar functions in computed columns is a bad idea](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/01/another-reason-why-scalar-functions-in-computed-columns-is-a-bad-idea/) – Erik Darling

[Be careful with constraints calling UDFs](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2009/12/17/be-careful-with-constraints-calling-udfs.aspx) – Tibor Karaszi

[Beware-row-row-operations-udf-clothing](http://sqlmag.com/database-development/beware-row-row-operations-udf-clothing) – Brian Moran

[Why does the Execution Plan include a scalar udf call for a persisted computed column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998217/why-does-the-execution-plan-include-a-user-defined-function-call-for-a-computed)  – Stack Overflow

Comment: I also need to remove holidays when finding the difference between two dates, so a calendar table was best fit for that purpose.